# Плагин Password Protected на WordPress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины, password

Работает ли плагин Password Protected на версии WP 5.6. Если работает, то у меня не получается его запустить. При заходе никакого пароля не требуется. Если не работает, то чем можно заменить? Мне требуется устанавливать пароль на весь сайт, чтобы доступ к нему был только у узкого круга лиц

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Работает, только что проверил. Вы какие-то настройки туда вводите?

Comment: Добавил скрин с настройками. И еще, плагин же в любом случае будет работать? Или сайт должен быть построен в редакторе самого WP? До залива на WP сайт писал на локальном чистом сервере. php-js-css-mysql ничего больше нет

Comment: Гуглим "базовая авторизация" и никаких плагнов не надо. Или вообще фейковый/левый домен с записями в хостс.

Comment: Написано же - совместим до 5.5.3 https://ru.wordpress.org/plugins/password-protected/

Answer (score 0):

Проверил плагин, установив его на тестовом сайте с WP 5.6. Он работает.Чтобы проверить, надо разлогиниться. Залогиненным пользователям доступ к сайту есть всегда.